# Reshape DataFrame into 3D array for RNN Keras-tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

**The problems**

I have 31 days of transaction data of each customer before they churn(some customer has less than 31 days) in Dataframe
How to reshape it to 3D array and pad with 0 for Keras RNN? and
Make sure that it matches with other Dataframe of target

**Data structure**

This toy sample to work with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Customer_id' : [112]*27 + [223]*31 + [256]*30
        ,'DATE' : np.concatenate([np.concatenate([np.arange(20200701,20200728) , np.arange(20200501,20200532)]), np.arange(20200501,20200531)])
        ,'Last_date_before_churn' :[20200727]*27 + [20200531]*31 + [20200530]*30
        ,'Feature1':np.random.uniform(0.1,0.9,88)
        ,'Feature2':np.random.uniform(0.1,0.9,88)
    })

# edit to replicate actual data
df = df.drop(15,axis = 0)


target = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_id' : [256,112,223]
    ,'IS_Churn':[1,0,1]
})
```

We have 3 customers [112,223,256]. 112 has 27 days before he not churn and 223 has 31 days before he churns.
The current shape is (88, 4) but we need to reshape to (3,31,2) -> 3 customer, 31-time step, and 2 features. So that the third dimension is each Customer_id which align with a target data frame

**The other difficult part is**

each customer has a different date range. while we can look at the 'Last_date_before_churn' is the last date in the 31 day range.
for example, the Last date of Customer 112 is 27 July, we might have data of the only date from the 1st July to 15 July and then from 17 July to 27 July. So we should pad the date from 27 June to 30 June, and then 16 July as well so that it becomes 31 days

**What I have tried**

I tried using for loop but took forever for my actual data of 27,928,258 rows dataset

```
result = []
for index, Cid in enumerate(df.Customer_id.unique()):
    result.append(df[df['Customer_id'] == Cid].iloc[:, :])
```

Comment: Instead of doing that, why don't you create a variable that stores that column, then reshape it into 3D array? Note that the DataFrame can only hold 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for that huge a data my solution will work or not.
I will take a go at it anyway.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Customer_id' : [112]*27 + [223]*31 + [256]*30
        ,'DATE' : np.concatenate([np.concatenate([np.arange(20200701,20200728) , np.arange(20200501,20200532)]), np.arange(20200501,20200531)])
        ,'Feature1':np.random.uniform(0.1,0.9,88)
        ,'Feature2':np.random.uniform(0.1,0.9,88)
    })
    
# Getting unique customer ids.
Series_customer_ids = df['Customer_id'].unique()

# Final array having the result.
final = np.zeros((Series_customer_ids.shape[0], 31, 2))

# Used for indexing first dimension of `final`
i = 0

for customer_id in Series_customer_ids:
    # `n_days` is the number of days for each customer. Assumed <=31.
    n_days = df[df['Customer_id']==customer_id].shape[0]
    if n_days > 0:
        np.place(
            # Location in `final` array.
            final[i],
            # Mask
            [(True, True) for _ in range(31)],
            # Pad for 31 - `n_days`.
            np.pad(
                df[df['Customer_id']==customer_id][['Feature1', 'Feature2']].to_numpy(),
                ((0, 31 - n_days), (0,0)),
                'constant'
            )
        )
    i += 1

# `final` contains the answer.

print(final.shape)
# (customer id count, days of month, features per observation)
# (3, 31, 2)
```

Once again it could fail due to memory limitations or will just take forever to complete.

Comment: Thank you, Puneet. Your answer nails it.
I forget to mention the other difficult part of the problem which is padding for each different date range. I just added it to the question. Please help Thank you.